# making big data set smaller in excel

Tags: excel, dataset

I made a little test machine that accidentally created a 'big' data set:
6 columns with +/- 550.000 rows.

The end result I am looking for is a graph with 6 lines, horizontal axis 1 - 550.000 measurements and vertically the values in the rows. (capped at 200 or so). Data is a resistance measurement that should be between 0 - 30 or very big (borken), the software writes 'inf' in these cases.

My skill is limited to excel, so what have I done until now:

Imported in Excel. The measurements are valuable between 0 - 30 and inf is not good for a graph, so I did: if(cell>200){200}else{keep cell value}.
Now making a graph is a timely exercise and excel does not like this, result is not good.
So I would like to take the average value of 60 measurements to reduce the rows to below 10.000. So =AVERAGE(H1:H60)
But I cannot get this to work.

Questions:

1. How do I reduce this data set and get a good graph.
2. Should I switch
   to other software that is more applicable?

FYI: I already changed the software of the testing device to take the average value of a bunch of measurements the next time... But I cannot repeat this test.

[Download link of data set comma separated file 17MB](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/8f74892f34dc172223efab0a45e6589120160616081452/fa5f54)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, however my guess is that you only want to get an average every 60 rows and are unsure how to do this. 
Using `MOD(Number, Divisor)` inside an if statement will let you specify that the average should be calculated only once in every x number of cells.

Assuming you'll have one row above your data table for headers, you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A61),60) = 1,AVERAGE(H2:H61),"")
```

Once you have this you can filter your average column to non-blank values and use this to create your graph.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! This is great.
I copied the data to separate excel sheet. removed the 'empty' rows by searching and selecting anything but numbers (blanks did not work). made the graph!